# Assigning NavigationLink to Images within Array in Swift UI

Tags: arrays, swift, image, swiftui, lazyvgrid

I have an array of images that I am passing through a LazyVgrid.

I am wondering how I assign a NavigationLink to the Image names stored within the array, clicking icon1 navigates to page1, ect for all 8.

------ Swift UI -------

```
import SwiftUI

    struct Grid: View {
        var images: [String] = ["icon1", "icon2", "icon3", "icon4",
                                 "icon5", "icon6", "icon7","icon8"]
        
        var columnGrid: [GridItem] = [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 25), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 25)]
        
        var body: some View {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columnGrid, spacing: 50) {
                ForEach(images, id:\.self) { image in
                    Image(image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.75 ) - 1,
                               height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2.75 ) - 1)
                        .clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(25)
                        
                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64230971/12299030?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For occasions like this I would prefer an enum that holds all related information. You also could do this with a struct the reasoning behind this stays the same.

```
enum ImageEnum: String, CaseIterable{ //Please find a better name ;)
    case image1, image2 
    
    var imageName: String{ // get the assetname of the image
        switch self{
        case .image1:
            return "test"
        case .image2:
            return "test2"
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var detailView: some View{ // create the view here, if you need to add
        switch self{           // paramaters use a function or associated
        case .image1:          // values for your enum cases
            TestView1()
        case .image2:
            TestView2()
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct TestView1: View{
    var body: some View{
        Text("test1")
    }
}

struct TestView2: View{
    var body: some View{
        Text("test2")
    }
}
```

---

And your `Grid` View:

```
struct Grid: View {
    
    var columnGrid: [GridItem] = [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 25), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 25)]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{ // Add the NavigationView
            LazyVGrid(columns: columnGrid, spacing: 50) {
                ForEach(ImageEnum.allCases, id:\.self) { imageEnum in // Iterate over all enum cases
                    NavigationLink(destination: imageEnum.detailView){ // get detailview here
                        Image(imageEnum.imageName) // get image assset name here
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .clipped()
                            .cornerRadius(25)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: What an amazing reply, thank you ever so much

Comment: I've ran this through a test and i'm not getting any images showing on the main screen, i think i'm miss understanding the structure, does Testview1 sit within a new file or with the ImageEmun as i thought this wouldn't make a different

Comment: @Flamee did you manage to get it to work? If not try renaming the return values in `imageName` var in your enum to match the asset names in your case e.g. `icon1`....

Comment: It's all working perfectly now! thank you! Did some playing with it